# List all symbols in a dylib

Tags: c++, c, macos

I'm trying to list all the symbols inside a dylib in order to know which one needs to be updated inside my app (as my app store all links to function as well as their name , to create a dynamic module mechanism that auto detect/update functions automatically at runtime).

Basically what Im searching for is similar as what the nm command do but in code (and not by launching nm on the console then get the output and parse).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [rsym_macosx](http://modular.math.washington.edu/home/wstein/www/home/page/fricas-src/gcl/unixport/rsym_macosx.c%20rsym_macosx) could give you some helps to do something like `nm`. I don't know what kind of symbols you really want to do within your code, but you could modify it based on that and Mach-O format.